# Typo3 custom content with 2 headers

Tags: typo3

I am trying to create a new `content element` (not sure if its the correct name for it) and i want to achieve something like this

## HEADER_1

### HEADER_2

body  text

in my tt_content.php file i have the following:

```
'showitem' => '
          --div--;Intro,
             --palette--;LLL:EXT:/path/to/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.general;
             general,
             header,
             bodytext,
             module_background_color,
             --palette--;;cta,
```

I tried to add something like this

```
'showitem' => '
          --div--;Intro,
             --palette--;LLL:EXT:/path/to/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.general;
             general,
             header,
             header,
             bodytext,
             module_background_color,
             --palette--;;cta,
```

or this

```
'showitem' => '
          --div--;Intro,
             --palette--;LLL:EXT:/path/to/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.general;
             general,
             header,
             bodytext,
             bodytext,
             module_background_color,
             --palette--;;cta,
```

both didnt work and i can only get 1 header and 1 body text, i am so new to this and somehow i need to do it

p.s i can't do it via 1 header because every header has its own styling.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One column can only be used once!

Take an look in the `header` element. Here you can see an column named `subheader`.

so following should add another header column:

```
'showitem' => '
          --div--;Intro,
             --palette--;LLL:EXT:/path/to/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.general;
             general,
             header,
             subheader,
             bodytext,
             module_background_color,
             --palette--;;cta,
```

Comment: this did the job, but just out of curiosity where do i find the header element ?

Comment: When you go to `Configuration` and select `Table configuration array` in the dropdown, you can go to "tt_content" and collapse this path. Now you can collapse `types` and `header`. Now you can see which columns are used by this element. You can see that an palette `headers` is used. So you can collapse the sections `palettes` and `headers` now you see that there is `subheader` included. You can also add this content element an click right on fields to get the field names in the inspector of your browser.